# Getting error in web.xml for spring mvc project

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am creating Spring MVC project.

In web.xml at `<spring-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</spring-class>`

I am getting this error

> "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'spring-  class'. One of
>   `{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":servlet-class, "http:// 
>   xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":jsp-file,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":init-  param,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":load-on-startup,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/  xml/ns/javaee":enabled,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":async-supported,
>
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":run-as,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/  javaee":security-role-ref,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":multipart-config}` is
>   expected."

Could anyone help me out with this

Comment: Without providing a [mcve], it's difficult to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your complete web.xml posted it is hard to determine but from what you posted I believe your issue maybe the space between the hyphen and class.

You have `'spring- class'` but it should be `'spring-class'`

Comment: Here is my web.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
version="3.1">
 <display-name>Hello</display-name>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <spring-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</spring-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>